# AutoMapper Model To ViewModel Vice Versa Updating Record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, automapper

I have a unit test which I use mapper from Model to ViewModel, and ViewModel back to Model the Update the record - but in reality I haven't changed a thing, just testing that updating works.

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void UpdateEntry()
    {
        //Map Model to ViewModel
        Mapper.CreateMap<GlobalExport, GlobalExportViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<FileNameSetup, FileNameSetupViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<FileNameVariable, FileNameVariableViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<EmailSetup, EmailSetupViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<SelectedSection, SelectedSectionViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<AvailableSection, AvailableSectionViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<AvailableColumn, AvailableColumnViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Policy, PolicyViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<SelectedColumn, SelectedColumnViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<SelectedEmployeeSeaServiceType, SelectedEmployeeSeaServiceTypeViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<SelectedEmployeeStatus, SelectedEmployeeStatusViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<EmployeeStatus, EmployeeStatusViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<EmployeeSubStatus, EmployeeSubStatusViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<SelectedEmployeeSubStatus, SelectedEmployeeSubStatusViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<SelectedSeaServiceType, SelectedSeaServiceTypeViewModel>();


        GlobalExport globalExport = _service.GetGlobalExportById(1);
        GlobalExportViewModel globalExportViewModel = Mapper.Map<GlobalExport, GlobalExportViewModel>(globalExport);

        //Map ViewModel to Model
        Mapper.CreateMap<GlobalExportViewModel, GlobalExport>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<FileNameSetupViewModel, FileNameSetup>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<FileNameVariableViewModel, FileNameVariable>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<EmailSetupViewModel, EmailSetup>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<SelectedSectionViewModel, SelectedSection>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<AvailableSectionViewModel, AvailableSection>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<AvailableColumnViewModel, AvailableColumn>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<PolicyViewModel, Policy>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<SelectedColumnViewModel, SelectedColumn>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<SelectedEmployeeSeaServiceTypeViewModel, SelectedEmployeeSeaServiceType>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<SelectedEmployeeStatusViewModel, SelectedEmployeeStatus>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<EmployeeStatusViewModel, EmployeeStatus>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<EmployeeSubStatusViewModel, EmployeeSubStatus>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<SelectedEmployeeSubStatusViewModel, SelectedEmployeeSubStatus>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<SelectedSeaServiceTypeViewModel, SelectedSeaServiceType>();

        GlobalExport newGlobalExport = Mapper.Map<GlobalExportViewModel, GlobalExport>(globalExportViewModel);
        _service.UpdateGlobalExport(newGlobalExport);

    }
```

I get this error:

[image: Error]

Can somebody give some opinion or better a solution :P Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `GlobalExportRepository.UpdateGlobalExport` method is attempting to attach a `GlobalExport` object to the same [DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679505%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) instance that retrieved it.

Try modifying the `GlobalExportRepository.UpdateGlobalExport` method to explicitly mark the entity as modified and simply call the [DbContext.SaveChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method.

Here's an example:

```
public void UpdateGlobalExport(GlobalExport instance)
{
    var entity = context.Entry(instance);
    entity.State = EntityState.Modified;        
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Any changes made to the `GlobalExport` instance [will automatically be detected even if its state is Detached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696243%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Comment: I'll look into it and get back to you. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm sorry to say that the state returned equals to EntityState.Detached, so the error is still there :( What will happen if I changed the condition to reverse "!entity.State" ?

Comment: @Badz Try removing the call to the `DbSet.Attach` method altogether. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Badz At what line do you get the exception?

Comment: I got the exception on this part - context.SaveChanges();
It's ok now, my colleague already solved it. Thanks for the troubles